# Trying to filter NSMutableArray with NSPredicate and getting error

Tags: ios

I'm trying to filter the results of a list of employee contacts that I keep in my app but am getting the following error : 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection LAST (not a collection)'

I've tried several variations with the NSPredicate command, self, self.last, employee.last, last == 'smith' (this one doesn't generate an error but doesn't return any results).

```
NSMutableArray *employeesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Person2 *employee = [[Person2 alloc] init];

employee.first = @"bob";
employee.last = @"black";
[employeesList addObject:employee];

employee = [[Person2 alloc] init];
employee.first = @"jack";
employee.last = @"brown";
[employeesList addObject:employee];

employee = [[Person2 alloc] init];
employee.first = @"george";
employee.last = @"smith";
[employeesList addObject:employee];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"last contains[cd] %@", @"black"];
NSArray *filteredKeys = [employeesList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"filtered : %@",filteredKeys);
```

[person2.h]

```
@interface Person2 : NSObject

{
  @private  
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *first;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *last;

+ (Person2 *)personWithFirst:(NSString *)first andLast:(NSString *)last;

@end
```

[person2.m]

```
#import "Person2.h"

@implementation Person2
@synthesize first, last;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    }

return self;
}

+ (Person2 *)personWithFirst:(NSString *)first andLast:(NSString *)last {
Person2 *person = [[Person2 alloc] init];
[person setFirst:first];
[person setLast:last];
return person;
} 

- (NSString *)description {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self first], [self last]];
}

@end
```

Comment: howz your employeesList look like ??? your array is object of array why you add multiple object in your array ?? its very bad

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Filtering of the array based on last name matching, or are you trying to retrieve the last person in the array with the last name matching?

Comment: I want to return an array of everyone that matches.

Comment: @iPatel - here is an NSLog of employeesList 
2013-09-05 09:41:54.205 test[6556:c07]  (
    "bob black",
    "jack brown",
    "george smith"
)

Comment: @sonicbabbler - then use NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@", @"black"];

Comment: @iPatel - I get the following error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object bob black.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer and now I feel very dumb!! The use of "first" and "last" are reserved names and cannot be used. I changed the variables to firstName and lastName and it works perfectly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html.

Thank you all for your comments and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an NSArray category that does this sort of thing easily:

```
@interface NSArray (FilterAdditions)
- (NSArray *)filterObjectsUsingBlock:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx))block;
@end


@implementation NSArray (FilterAdditions)

- (NSArray *)filterObjectsUsingBlock:(BOOL (^)(id, NSUInteger))block {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (block(obj, idx)) {
            [result addObject:obj];
        }
    }];
    return result;
}
```

So you would call it like this:

```
NSArray *filteredEmployees = 
[employeeList filterObjectsUsingBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx){ 
    return [(Person2 *)obj.last isEqualToString:@"black"];
}];
```